# Text box not updating

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So there are these two heads on one slide (dragRec), each has a normal state, roll over, and drag. Endpoint prints to a textbox on drag that displays a relative position, and threshold is set to show the percentage between the left end of the slider and Endpoint. When you drag Endpoint its text updates, however when threshold is moved no text appears. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var textTimer:Timer = new Timer (10);
textTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,textUpdate);
textTimer.start();

var textTimer2:Timer = new Timer (10);
textTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,threshUpdate);
textTimer2.start();


function endDrag (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    endpoint.gotoAndStop("2");
    endpoint.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, endOver);   
    endpoint.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, endOut);
    endpoint.startDrag(false,dragRec);

    endpoint.endText.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,typeit);
}


function textUpdate2(event:FocusEvent):void
{

    endpoint.x = (354+(10.9*((Number(endpoint.endText.text)-19.5))));

    textTimer.start();
}

function textUpdate(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    position = Math.round(19.5-((354-endpoint.x)/10.9));
    endpoint.endText.text = position;

}
function endStopDrag (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //endpoint.gotoAndStop("1");
    endpoint.stopDrag();
}

function threshDrag (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    threshmc.gotoAndStop("2");
    threshmc.startDrag(false,threshRec);
    threshmc.threshp.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,threshtypeit);
}

function threshStopDrag (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    threshmc.stopDrag();

}

function threshUpdate2(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    if(Number(threshmc.threshp.text) < 1)
    {
        threshmc.threshp.text = 1;
    }
    threshmc.x = (141.45+(((-141.45+endpoint.x)*(Number(threshmc.threshp.text)))/100));
    textTimer2.start();
}


function threshUpdate(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        tposition = Math.round(((19.5-((354-threshmc.x)/10.9))/(19.5-((354-endpoint.x)/10.9)))*100);
        threshmc.threshTip.tpercent.text = tposition;
    }
```

Comment: That's quite the wall of text, why don't you post a [condensed example](http://sscce.org/) showing your problem?

Comment: This is condensed as I think I can make it.

Comment: What's the initial value of threshmc.threshp.text?, it must have a value that can be cast to Number according to threshUpdate2 function

Comment: threshUpdate2 is never called, right? Neither is textUpdate2. I would recommend removing those functions to help clarify the question.

Comment: Try trace() out as the first line of threshUpdate() to make sure it's at least getting called. Then trace out the tposition value before the text setting to make sure it's getting calculated as an actual value. Then trace out the value of your text field to make sure it's not null for some reason?

Comment: Hey thanks everyone I got a fix: I added a MouseMove listener to the stage during the threshdrag that called an update for the problematic threshp textbox. Then removed the listener on stopdrag...and ta-da. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was solved, so I'm restating the answer to the best of my abilities. If the user wants to add his/her own answer and accept that instead, that's fine by me. **This is just to get the question off of Unanswered.**

The user added a MouseMove listener to the stage during the threshdrag. This listener called the function that updated the textbox that wasn't working before. Then, the listener on stop drag was removed.